# Capybara unable to find input tag CSS element

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I'm trying to use capybara to find a CSS element but RSpec keeps returning unable to find element. I tried with id, class, and name.

HTML (using inspect element)

```
<input class="new_photo_upload_entry" type="file" name="photo_upload_entry[upload]" id="photo_upload_entry_upload">
```

steps.rb file

```
expect(page).to have_css('#photo_upload_entry_upload')
expect(page).to have_css('.new_photo_upload_entry')
expect(page).to have_css('input[name="photo_upload_entry[upload]"]')
```

Running cucumber feature result:

```
expected to find css "#photo_upload_entry_upload" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters. (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

expected to find css ".new_photo_upload_entry" but there were no matches (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

expected to find css "input[name=\"photo_upload_entry[upload]\"]" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters. (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for a file element, there's a high chance it's been hidden on the page (so that a different element can be styled the same across browsers).  This is common with most JS file upload helper libraries. if it's not actually visible on the page and you just want to confirm it exists in the page source you can pass visible: false as an option

```
expect(page).to have_css('#photo_upload_entry_upload', visible: false)
```

If however you next want to call `#attach_file` on it to upload a file, you'll need to use `execute_script(...)` to modify the css of the element to make it visible before you attach a file to it.

The other option is that the element isn't actually on the page (since all 3 of your finders should match the element if it existed and was visible).  You can check `page.html` to see what page is actually being used by capybara.

Comment: Having some hard time writing the JS script. `script = "document.getElementById(#photo_upload_entry_upload).style.visibility = 'visible';"`

Comment: It would all depend on how it's hidden - you may need display:block , you may need opactiy: 1, maybe z-index , maybe important! is needed on any of those settings too. Without knowing exactly what CSS is being applied to hide it, we can't know how to unhide it.

Comment: There was a CSS that was `display:none`, changed to `display:block`. Also I had to use the `name`, not `id` or `class` when using `#attach_file`

Comment: attach_file calls `find(:file_field, 'locator passed to attach_file')` to find the file input before setting the file to it --  that will take the text of a label attached to the input, the name of the input, or the id of the input ( no # in front of that because it's the id not a css selector). It doesn't take a class, and I'm guessing you tried the id with a # in front. - anyway, as long as you have it working all's good.